# why required attribute is not working in thymeleaf?

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to add validations on **Select Option** in form to fill all fields, but like html, in thymeleaf **required** attribute is not working.
I have tried multiple ways but nothing is working.

```
th:required=""
th:required="required"
required=""
required="required"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: i meant, those above options are not woking.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- in particular `Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question.`